# Pandas read_csv giving a larger dataframe than the one I wrote it with using pd.to_csv()

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I have a dataframe in one file I am writing to a csv using pd.to_csv() and then in another file I am opening that csv into a dataframe using pd.read_csv() but they are different sizes? The number of rows it the dataframe is larger when I am reading the csv back in the other file. Any thoughts on what this could be?

So here the snippet of code in question. I cleared the csv before running again and the shape of the df before writing to the csv was (32636, 28).
Opening it up the shape is (68450, 29).

I am only running this on 2 files currently.

[writing csv code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9bF03.png)

edit:

The json is twitter api data if that helps.

Comment: you are probably re-writing  to the file. first delete the file. then run your code

Comment: What is the size difference? Is it one row? or is it double the number of rows? Is it duplicating the header row, duplicating all the rows? Some other behavior? Please provide a more detailed description of the problem; a [mcve] would help

Comment: You're appending to the file.

Comment: [You should not post code as an image because...](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/1422451).

Comment: Also [never call `DataFrame.append` or `pd.concat` inside a for-loop. It leads to quadratic copying.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36489724/1422451)